# How to obtain all instances of a class within the current module

Tags: python, module, introspection

I have a module `foo` that defines a class `Foo`, and instantiates a number of instances of this class.

From other modules, I can `import foo` and obtain a list of the `Foo` objects instantiated by:

```
[getattr(foo,f) for f in dir(f) if isinstance(getattr(foo,f), foo.Foo)]
```

It would be convenient if I could do this from within the module `foo`. But as written, the name `foo` is meaningless inside `foo`, and changing to `self` doesn't help.

Is there a way to use introspection within this module to find all instances of this class? I was hoping there was a way to avoid making a list and appending each instance.

Comment: I suggest renaming this "how to get all instantiated instances of a class", assuming that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> goal: "*`import foo` and obtain a list of the Foo objects instantiated by...*"

You don't need introspection at all. Imagine this is your class:

```
class Registered(object):
    _all = set()
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__._all.add(self)
```

Demo; instantiate a bunch of objects and refer to them:

```
>>> Registered()
>>> Registered()
>>> Registered()

>>> Registered._all
{<__main__.Registered object at 0xcd3210>, <__main__.Registered object at 0xcd3150>, <__main__.Registered object at 0xcd31d0>}
```

Since you are using `dir`, if I understand you correctly, you are trying to find all the objects in the current module's global variables. However it doesn't really get you all the objects in the current module, only those bound to variables. If that's what you really want, you can do `{var for name,var in globals() if isinstance(var,Foo)}`

If that's not what you really want, you can modify the above to keep track of the module the object was defined in via `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals` or something, but this would prevent you from using factory functions defined in `foo.py` or in other modules.

If you are actually trying to get all instances of something created in a module, this is a sign of a serious coding issue however; consider perhaps writing a factory function wrapper in that module, which does nothing except pass along the initialization args and return the result, keeping track of initialized objects.

Comment: When I try this I get `NameError: global name '__class__' is not defined`

Comment: @FarmBoy: replace `__class__` with `Registered`; it's a nicer way to do things in python3 (if you decide to change the name of your class, you don't have to replace it every time you used it)

Comment: You can use `type(self)`. Or override `__new__` instead.

Comment: `self.__all__` will be the same `set` as `Registered.__all__`, so long as you don't *assign to it*.  Also `__all__` is a terrible name for this.  It should probably be `_all` or `__all`,  names beginning and ending with two underscores are reserved for future definition by python, and since `__all__` does not specifically have this use in python, it shouldn't match the reserved pattern.

Comment: I suggest using weak references for the objects in the set.  Otherwise it will be hard to collect them.

Comment: @Dietrich: very good idea! Thank you very much. @TokenMacGuy: you're right, perhaps it would be better to do something like initialize if `not hasattr(__class__,'registry')`, then `__class__.registry.add(...)`, and it conflicts with use of `__all__` in __init__.py`-files. I don't mind it so much but it is a valid concern which I did not mention.

Comment: I would still leave the initialization of the attribute in the class body, since that's a bit easier to read.  the point I was trying to make is that you don't need to use `self.__class__` at all, `self` is fine.